# Rails validations using errors.add

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a separate method in my model to validate like this:

```
validate :validate_id

def validate_id
    errors.add(:base, "Id Should Not Blank") if self.project_id.blank?
end
```

I need to perform a validation which would be like this:

validates_format_of :project_id, :with => /^(?!\d+$)[a-z0-9-_]*$/

which would validate letters and numbers with only underscore and dash and no spaces between them.

Is there any possible way to use it in my method validate_id.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
def validate_id
  errors.add(:base, "Id Should Not Blank") if /^(?!\d+$)[a-z0-9-_]*$/.match(self.project_id).nil?
end
```

Comment: self.project_id.scan(/^(?!\d+$)[a-z0-9\-_]*$/).empty? == true
this worked too.

Thanks

Comment: welcome @Hivltg, #scan returns everything that the Regex matches and #match returns the first match as a MatchData object.